# word2Vec vector representation for text classification algorithm

Tags: python, word2vec, word-embedding

I am trying to use word2vec in text classification algorithm.
I want t create vectorizer using word2vec, I have used below script. But I am not able to get one row for each document instead I am getting matrix of different dimension for every document. 
For example for 1st document matrix of 31X100,  2nd 163X100 and 3rd 73X100 and so on.
Actually I need dimension of every document as 1X100 , so that i can use these as input feature for training model

Can anyone help me here.

```
import os
import pandas as pd       
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords # Import the stop word list
import gensim
import numpy as np

train = pd.read_csv("Data.csv",encoding='cp1252')
wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def Description_to_words(raw_Description):
    Description_text = BeautifulSoup(raw_Description).get_text() 
    letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", Description_text)
    words = word_tokenize(letters_only.lower())    
    stops = set(stopwords.words("english")) 
    meaningful_words = [w for w in words if not w in stops]
    return( " ".join(wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in meaningful_words))

num_Descriptions = train["Summary"].size
clean_train_Descriptions = []
print("Cleaning and parsing the training set ticket Descriptions...\n")
clean_train_Descriptions = []
for i in range( 0, num_Descriptions ):
    if( (i+1)%1000 == 0 ):
        print("Description %d of %d\n" % ( i+1, num_Descriptions ))
    clean_train_Descriptions.append(Description_to_words( train["Summary"][i] ))

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(clean_train_Descriptions, size=100)
w2v = dict(zip(model.wv.index2word, model.wv.syn0))

class MeanEmbeddingVectorizer(object):
    def __init__(self, word2vec):
        self.word2vec = word2vec
        # if a text is empty we should return a vector of zeros
        # with the same dimensionality as all the other vectors
        #self.dim = len(word2vec.itervalues().next())
        self.dim = 100

    def fit(self, X, y):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return np.array([
            np.mean([self.word2vec[w] for w in words if w in self.word2vec]
                    or [np.zeros(self.dim)], axis=0)
            for words in X
        ])

a=MeanEmbeddingVectorizer(w2v)
clean_train_Descriptions[1]
a.transform(clean_train_Descriptions[1])

train_Descriptions = []
for i in range( 0, num_Descriptions ):
    if( (i+1)%1000 == 0 ):
        print("Description %d of %d\n" % ( i+1, num_Descriptions ))
    train_Descriptions.append(a.transform(" ".join(clean_train_Descriptions[i])))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issues in your code causing problems, both easily solved.

First, Word2Vec requires sentences to be actually a list of words, rather than an actual sentence as a single string. So from your `Description_to_words` just return the list, don't join.

`return [wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in meaningful_words]`

Since word2vec iterates over each sentence to get the words, previously it was iterating over a string, and you were actually getting a character level embedding from `wv`.

Secondly, a similar issue with the way you are calling transform - `X` is expected to be a list of documents, not an individual document. So when you are doing `for words in X`, you are actually creating a list of characters, and then iterating over that to create embedding. So your output was actually the individual character embeddings for each character in your sentences. Simply changed, just convert all documents at once!

`train_Descriptions = a.transform(clean_train_Descriptions)`

(to do one at a time, wrap in a list (`[clean_train_Descriptions[1]]`), or select 1 using the range selector( `clean_train_Descriptions[1:2]`).

With those two changes you should get 1 row back per input sentence.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help. I was struggling to get solution for this for more than 2 weeks.